# Adding img tags into a Django template using Javascript

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, django, django-templates, dynamic-content

Hi so I am trying to make a website in django. For one page on the website I want to have a catalog so I need to load in a big table using javascript. The console.log is the correct img tag syntax but no images load.

This is my javascript code : catolog.js

```
function makeList() {
    listData = Array.from(Array(43).keys()); 
    // Add it to the page
    content1 = document.querySelectorAll(".tg-0lax");
    var count = 0;
    var td;
    for (td of content1){
            console.log(td);
            text =   'images'+ '/'+ 'image_' + count + '.jpg';
            console.log(text);
            img = " src= \"{ % static '" + text + "' % }\"";
            str = '<img ' + img + '>';
            console.log(str);
        td.innerHTML = str;
        count = count + 1;
    }
}
makeList();
```

This is my html file

```
{% extends "storeApp/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{%load static%}

<style>
article{
        text-align: center;

}
</style>
<div class="content1" id="data-point-1">
        <style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;
  overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;
  font-weight:normal;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-0lax{text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
</style>
<table class="tg" onload="makeList()">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-0lax"></th>
    <th class="tg-0lax"></th>
    <th class="tg-0lax"></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
```

.
.
.

```
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<script src={% static 'js/catolog.js'%}>

</script>

</div>




{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What is the value of the `src` property when you log the image element?

Comment: <img  src= "{ % static 'images/image_3.jpg' % }" alt="" >

Comment: So that means that Django doesn't render the static path to your images. And it shouldn't. If you need local variables from Python to JavaScript, then output your static path value in a dictionary, turn it into JSON and put it in a `<script>` tag on your page. Now JavaScript can read that JSON from the script and use the properties to create your path correctly.